# Liquibase config file content?

Tags: java, liquibase

I am trying to integrate Liquibase for my current project. I have read the Quick Start Guide and the Documentation pages. I want to use it via it's API. When i run it like they say on the site, it complains about a missing config file. So i have created the liquibaseConfig.yml. But the system still complains the file does not exist, but it is there. What content should the config file have? Here is how i call the liquibase API:

```
Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance()
        .findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(connection));

  Liquibase liquibase = new liquibase.Liquibase(DEFAULT_LIQUIBASE_CONFIGFILE, new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(),
        database);

  liquibase.update(new Contexts(), new LabelExpression());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question the solution lies in the RessourceAccessor type. I changed it to FileSystemResourceAccessor and it works.

```
Liquibase liquibase = new liquibase.Liquibase(DEFAULT_LIQUIBASE_CONFIGFILE, new FileSystemResourceAccessor(),
        database);
```